# url only available by IP address after rewriteRule

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I am not very familiar with apache rewrite. Tried to add a line as following to one of our virtual hosts config in apache

```
RewriteRule /favicon.ico http://example.com/favicon.ico [R=301,L]
```

then try to access it using:

`http://myexample.com/favicon.ico`

I got 404. However, if I use:

`http://theIP/favicon.ico`

I got the right redirect. Totally confused.

Would really appreciate it if someone can share some hints/thoughts. Thank you

Comment: What are you aiming to achieve with this `RewriteRule`, are you trying to point the favicon to one under `example.com`?

Comment: yes, if it is accessed by http://myserver.com/favicon.ico, then it should redirect to http://example.com/favicon.ico. But right now http://myserver.com/favicon.ico results in 404, only http://myserverIP/favicon.ico works  :(